# Django REST Framework] AssertionError: Class Serializer missing "Meta" attribute

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm following the DRF tutorial instructions at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/ but an assertion error happened. Here are my codes.(They're exactly the same as the codes from the tutorial website.)
I know that `class: Meta` is required when `ModelSerializer` is used. But here I used `Serializer` not `ModelSerializer`.

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles

LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted([(item, item) for item in get_all_styles()])


class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Snippet, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, STYLE_CHOICES


class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    code = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    linenos = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    language = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python')
    style = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Snippet.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.code = validated_data.get('code', instance.code)
        instance.linenos = validated_data.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
        instance.language = validated_data.get('language', instance.language)
        instance.style = validated_data.get('style', instance.style)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

and I entered the codes below at the command line(python manage.py shell).

```py
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

snippet = Snippet(code='foo = "bar"\n')
snippet.save()

snippet = Snippet(code='print("hello, world")\n')
snippet.save()

serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
serializer.data
```

Then the error happened. Can anyone help me with this problem please?

Comment: can you attach the error message also, i've tested your code and it worked just fine..

Comment: @MohabKhaled the message was `AssertionError: Class SnippetSerializer missing “Meta” attribute` but I just decided to use ModelSerializer instead and solved the problem anyways... I can't understand why the code didn't work on mine but worked on yours. But still, thanks for trying it out for me!